How do I handle a mongodb id between angular and mongoose?
Because of Typescript's strong typing, I am passing Mongodb's _id as a string in angular. Example:
public setSelectedProduct = async (productId: string) => {...}

When I pass productId to the backend and try to access Mongodb using Mongoose in Node.js, it tells me productId is not a valid Mongodb id.
exports.getProduct = async (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.params.productId', req.params.productId)
  const productId = req.params.productId;

  // const productId = new    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Number(req.params.productId));


  try {
   const product = await Product.findOne({_id: productId})
    console.log('product', product);
    // res.status(200).json(product);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Problem getting selected product.");
  }
}


CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 67420003204128e379f42946" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

I try to convert from string to ObjectId using the following:
 const productId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Number(req.params.productId));

But the existing associated product is not returned.
How do I handle this?

have you considered findById instead of findOne?

The string in that error starts with a space, was that a copy/paste failure?

The space before the id was the problem. But it must have been put there somewhere along the way. The _id came directly from a set of products that was queried. Nowhere was it manually modified.

Before specifically performing the query, Mongoose has a method that checks if the passed ObjectId is valid. Another point that's often useful is to perform the conversion using Mongoose's own method: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("").
